# How to create a a:d:b vector to create and display "sin(0), sin(pi/n), sin((2*pi)/n), . . . , sin(2*pi)]"

Tags: matlab, vector

I have been trying for a while to get this to work but I don't seem to be getting any closer to a solution.

I'm not sure of what the pattern is and what to write for the "d" value in a:d:b

Comment: What you did till now? Show your effort

Comment: You need to start learning the basics of MATLAB. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service, nor a homework writing service. You might occasionally get help from well-meaning users who feel sorry for you, but this is not sustainable in the long run. Do a tutorial. Read the documentation. All of your last 4 questions along this line were trivial.

Comment: Sorry about that! I just started learning matlab (about 3-4 days ago) and I compile a bunch of variety of questions and have chosen to ask the here (the few I don't get at all). I do put effort, but I don't show it with the question I post because I fell as though it might just be unnecessary information. You do have a good point though. Showing my steps, and you all telling me how to complete my steps or what to change instead of a full solution will help me more than just an answer. Again, sorry if it seemed like I was trying to leech answers from this site.

Comment: @Ineedhelp in case you're not aware of this, MATLAB's help and online documentation is superb. Their [Getting started](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) page is very good for, well, getting started. Reading through that will give you a lot of insight into the basic workings of the language. And thanks for understanding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you want to start from `0` (a) and go to `2*pi` (b).

Now the question comes what is your step size (d)?
From your example you can see that you are changing from `0` to `pi/n`.
And from `pi/n` to `2*pi/n`.

This means your step size is `d=pi/n`

Once you defined your `n`, e.g:

```
n=10;
```

you can do the rest like this:

```
x=0:(pi/n):(2*pi)
y=sin(x);
```

Comment: Looking at OP's new questions, they really need to start learning the basics of matlab, and writing their own homework. When you run into their third question, please suggest them to do so ;)